# How to merge multiple Open Api Spec into one using springdoc

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, springdoc

I have a micro service architecture with spring cloud gateway and each micro service has its own Open Api Spec. I need to merge all of them into 1 Open Api Spec ( yaml or json ).
I am not talking about a single swagger UI serving multiple links. I really need to merge the specs because the consumer of the spec needs a single json file.
This file is used by Open Api Validator by Atlassian.

Comment: No, but I did some research and it seems I can manually merge the 2 json obtained from 2 different micro service and create an endpoint for the merged version. It's a terrible solution for me